# Where the 'Rehearse Timings' values saved in PowerPoint file?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have just created a powerpoint content file, and put a click event to all bullet points. After I rehearsed the timing for each bullet points using "Rehearse Timings". Now I want to see where the timing value for each bullet points saved. I can only see the new duration values for each slide transition. But I cannot able to see where rehearsed timing values saved for each bullet points.

Any help where I can see rehearsed time value for bullet points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to view these timings via the user interface, but you can view them using VBA code.
They're stored in a tag named TIMING on the slide object and look like this:

TIMING  |4.5|3.4|3.7|1.4|0.2

Here's a little code that'll display the timings for each slide:

```
Sub thing()
Dim x As Long
Dim oSl As Slide
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides

 Debug.Print "Slide: " & oSl.SlideIndex
 For x = 1 To oSl.Tags.Count
    Debug.Print vbTab; oSl.Tags.Name(x) & vbTab & oSl.Tags.Value(x)
 Next

Next    ' Slide
End Sub
```

Comment: I will check this out and will let you know.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, where the timings will show up?

Comment: As mentioned above, they don't show up anywhere in the user interface.

Comment: I meant previously, I saved this code in VBA windows as a module, and it is showing up in Macro dialog box, if I play this macro nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have the immediate window open and have you recorded slide timings already?  Press Ctrl+G to open the immediate window in the VB IDE.  That's where Debug.Print messages appear.

Comment: Oh great! got it the timings are appearing in immediate window.

Comment: You can also edit those timings by using `Slide.Tags.Add "TIMING", "|1|2|3|4|5"` and if you want to create them from scratch, note that they won't work unless the **Transitions** timing is set to **Advance** the slide **After** X seconds

Answer (score 0):

1. rename pptx->zip
2. locate folder /pub/slides
3. for each slide{NN}.xml locate tag "advTm" and its value

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail to your answer.  More explanation of why this is an alternative to the accepted answer

Comment: That's useful information, especially for someone who's writing code to modify a PPTX file w/o launching/automating PowerPoint